# Old Shortcut Is Not Removed from Start Menu on Product Upgrade when using Windows Server 2012

Tags: wix, windows-installer, windows-server-2012

When our product upgrades on a Windows Server 2012 machine, the old shortcut is left behind in the Start menu.  The executable is removed from the system, but the old shortcut remains which causes an error when a user clicks it since it is not longer on the system.

This does not happen on windows 2008 R2, and I do not think there is a problem with how our msi is built.  I am asking the question here to see if others have experienced the same issue.

In case it may help, we are building the msi with WiX and here is the code snippet:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="The_ShortCut">
  <Component Id="The_ShortCut" Guid="{our-guid}">
    <Shortcut Id="TheShortCut.exe"
                                Name="Config Wizard"
                                Description="$(var.ProductNameLong)"
                                Target="[ShortCutFolder]OurCompany.Product.TheShortCut.exe"
                                WorkingDirectory="ShortCutFolder"
              Icon="TheShortcutIcon.Ico">
      <Icon Id="TheShortcutIcon.Ico" SourceFile="oursourcepath"/>
    </Shortcut>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\OurCompany\OurProduct" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="Remove_Product" Directory="OurCompany"  On="uninstall"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="Remove_Product_ShortCut" Directory="OurProduct_ShortCut" On="uninstall"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: Seeing that the problem only occurs on 2012 and not 2k8 then i would say that its not your WiX code or your MSI... I Would be interested to know how the value of `Directory = "OurProduct_ShortCut"` is obtained?
Maybe something to do with how the product directory is made ... or shortcut be kept in a different place in 2012 ?

Comment: @AltF4_. I am not clear what you are trying to tell me by your comment, would you rephrase it please?  I am not sure if your question is rhetorical or not.  If it's not, then I'm not sure how to answer it.

Comment: It was half and half really, I dint think the problem is the package but the code behind it. How do you obtain the value of "OurProduct_ShortCut"? isit hardcoded ? or does it have something like '%System%'attached to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this satisfactory answer from a coworker:

This doesn’t look like an issue with your package itself. The pinned item is just a reference to the *.lnk file at the location you had when you first pinned it. If you right-click the broken tile after upgrade and go to file location, it takes you the old shortcut folder (which no longer exists since the folder path has been changed).

It all seems like expected behavior. Judging from [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33a05ae9-7991-44b5-b00d-5552a38fa376/about-istartmenupinnedlist-interface-under-windows8), I’m not sure there’s a way to update the pinned item programmatically either.

Cheers!